# Latency on conditionally changing disable prop in a react mui5 component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I faced latency in enabling/disabling a material ui button conditionally.
It happens after migrating materialUi and reactjs into the latest version(react 18, mui/material: 5.10.10)
The sample which I am using read states from redux , then based on changed states, I expected disabled value is changed. It just happens for disable property, and haven't seen any latency if I change Button's text based on state changes.

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import  { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
 ......
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const {loading } = useSelector( reportSelector);
<Button 
 size='large'
 disabled={loading}
 > Execute
</Button>
```

If I check state before rendering the component, it works fine , but it is not the good solution.

```
{loading &&  <Button 
 size='large'
 disabled 
 > Execute
</Button>}
{!loading &&  <Button 
 size='large'
 > Execute
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the issue you are experiencing is due to the fact that you are using the useSelector hook inside the component rendering the Button element. The useSelector hook is a reference to the Redux store's selector function, and it is designed to be used inside a component that needs to access the state managed by the store.

In your case, it is possible that the useSelector hook is being called multiple times, potentially causing unnecessary re-renders of the component and leading to the latency you are experiencing. One way to fix this would be to move the useSelector hook outside the component and store the result in a variable that can be accessed by the component.

Comment: Thanks for your response, It was working fine before migration, and also If I just enable/disable button by checking state before rendering the component, it works fine. exp: { loading && <Button disable> Execute </Button>} {!loading && <Button> Execute </Button>}

Comment: I monitored the performance in profiler, and can see TransitionGroup(0.5ms) can it cause the latency?